# d3 force layout enter update exit

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
city a b c 
nyc  1 2 5
no   3 3 1
la   2 4 6
```

I'm trying to create a force layout that displays each value a,b,c by city. So at a time there would be three circles according to which city the user selects. Here is some of my code thus far:

```
function updateVisualization(){

var city = d3.select("#button").property("value");

var circle = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data);

circle.call(force.drag);

circle
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class","node");

circle
    .filter(function(d){
        return d.city == city;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d){
        return d.a
    })
    .attr("fill","red");

circle.exit().remove();
```

I repeat that for each circle, which works fine. My problem is with the `circle.exit().remove()`. Each time a user selects a city from the drop-down menu, the previous circles do not disappear as they should. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: can you give a complete example hosted online to show the problem?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add more parameters to the transition() and exit() functions.